# Database performance, tps & IOPS

Tags: performance, mariadb

We have a Java application that uses a MariaDB database that is dedicated to this application. The application needs to insert 1 million records within 5mins so ideally we would like the database to support a throughput of 5000 tps. Is there a calculation to work out the IOPS required to support a particular throughput? I am trying to understand the relationship between database tps and IOPS.

Comment: Although _theoretically speaking_ one could come up with some formula, in real life this question is simply and reliably answered by performance testing. Run you workload for five minutes and measure database logical and physical IO requests and the resulting storage IOPS, you'll have your answer right away.

Comment: Thank you. We will test this but the complexities of working in a large organisation means that we cant do it straight away. I just wanted to get an initial indication of whether the our 5000 tps requirement could be supported by a server that has a max of 2000 IOPS

Comment: 1 sec / 5000 tps = 0.2 mc

You need WAL (write-ahead logging) volume with  avg. latency 0.2 mc (seq.write 1 thread)

Answer (score -1):

Let me share my idea. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.
Seems it's not correct.
The application needs to insert 1 million records within 5mins so ideally, we would like the database to support a throughput of 5000 tps.
To understand how the system is critical which is calculated TPS and QPS.
TPS means Transaction per Second which consists might be one query or 10-15 quires need to complete one Transaction.
QPS means the Number of Query per second. Sharing your idea insert 1 million records
no matter how much time Taken it would be 1 TPS.
Seems it's very difficult to correlate TPS and IOPS.
TPS is database fact and IOPS is Storage Level. You need to calculate for Each TPS how IPOS is Okay. It's very difficult to say without understanding your system. If is Banking System for one LC/BC Operation(TPS) need lots of IOPS. Another side if it simple debit credit operation then a lot of operations do need not to have high IOPS.
Also, you need to Identify How much Read operation or Write Operation would happen in your system. Like different RAID policy would give you different Read and Write IOPS. If you are using SATA Disk you need to check rpm of the disk-like is it 7.2k, 10k or 15k rpm. You can mix SSD disks if your system required a lot of IOPS.